# sed command is working in solaris but not in Linux

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, sed

I am new to shell scripting and `sed` command.

The following `sed` command is working in Solaris but giving error in Linux:

```
sed -n 's/^[a-zA-z0-9][a-zA-z0-9]*[ ][ ]*\([0-9][0-9]*\).*[/]dir1[/]subdir1\).*/\2:\1/p'
```

**The error is**:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 79: Invalid range end
```

I have no clue why it is giving invalid range end error.

Comment: The character range `A-z` includes **all** characters with ASCII values between `A` and `z`.  That includes upper and lower alpha, as well as `[`, `]`, ```\```, `^`, `_`, and backtick.  That's probably not intentional, is it?

Comment: @Mr.Llama yes it is not intentional. It is working now once i change A-z to A-Z

Comment: `[a-zA-z0-9]` is equivalent to `[[:alnum:]]` (yes, with double brackets)

Comment: If you need a consistent syntax for sed between Solaris and Linux, you will be best served by installing GNU sed on your Solaris systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like Linux Sed doesn't like your `A-z` (twice). It doesn't really make sense, anyway.

Use `[A-Z]` (upper-case Z)

Comment: Thank you.. it is working with upper-case Z. Looks like solaris is interpreting it differently from Linux

Answer (score 3):

As blue112 said, `A-z` as a range makes no sense. Solaris sed is interpreting this as "the ASCII code for `A` through the ASCII code for `z`", in which case you could have unintended matches. `A-Z` occurs before `a-z` in ASCII, but there are a few characters falling between `Z` and `a`.

```
59 Y
5a Z
----
5b [
5c \
5d ]
5e ^
5f _
60 `
----
61 a
62 b
```

Here is an example showing Solaris sed (Solaris 8 in this case). Given this range, it substitutes `_` and `\` as well as the alphabetics you were apparently targeting.

```
% echo "f3oo_Ba\\r" | /usr/bin/sed  's/[A-z]/./g';echo
.3.....
```

(Note that the `3` was not substituted as it does not fall into the specified ASCII range.)

GNU sed is protecting you from shooting yourself in the foot by mistake.